# Jquery Animating Entire div Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> I need to move the entire div content from bottom to top on load, After 30 seconds onload i need to replace the **#content-box to #content-box2**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(Show_Alert());
            function Show_Alert() {
            $(function(){
            $("#content-box").animate({'bottom': 1900},700);
            });
        }   
  </script>

  <div id = "content-box">
        qwerty
  </div>

  <div id = "content-box2">
        1234567890
  </div>
```

Comment: Can it be done, in jquery?

Comment: sure It can done with jquery.. what do you meaning with replace?? ... replace positions? Is it fixed or absolute? or replace it in html structure .. its not clear for me .. so use [Make Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: div content should be replaced, qwerty should be replaced with 1234567890

Comment: you can see my answer .. hope it help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout('Show_Alert()', 30000);
    });

    function Show_Alert() {
        $("#content-box2").animate({'bottom': '1900px'},2000);
    }
```

And this CSS:

```
#content-box2 { position: absolute; bottom:0; left:0; width: 100%; }
```

If it doesn't help you could you please provide us the CSS for the content boxes and tell us what exactly should be happening after 30sec?

Answer (score 1):

to replace as you said in comment .. -in your case-  you can use `.html()`

```
$('#content-box').html($('#content-box2').html());
```

or you can use `.text()`

```
$('#content-box').text($('#content-box2').text());
```

Comment: Thank you Mohamed, i got it.